# Width não funciona em determinado tamanho da tela

Tags: javascript, html, css

Fiz uma barra lateral no meu site, e o width dela é alterado pelo javascript quando aperta um botão, e tudo funciona bem, mas se eu diminuir o tamanho da tela até um certo ponto o width para de funcionar, mesmo que eu altere o valor no inspecionar elemento.

OBS: O botão que ativa a função existe, mas não está nesse código.

```
<div id="sidebar_base">
        <div id="sidebar">
        </div>
</div>
```

```
div#sidebar {
    width: 50px;
    height: 100%;

    position: fixed;

    background-color: rgba(79, 79, 79, 1);

    transition: width 0.4s;
}

span#sidebar_base {
    width: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 50px;

    background-color: rgba(79, 79, 79, 1);

    transition: width 0.4s;
}
```

```
        function sidebarAnimation() {
            var sidebar = document.getElementById("sidebar");
            var sidebar_base = document.getElementById("sidebar_base");

            if(order) {
                sidebar.style.width="150px";
                sidebar_base.style.width="150px";
                
                order = false;
            } else {
                sidebar.style.width="50px";
                sidebar_base.style.width="50px";

                order = true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Cara edita a pergunta e coloca o mínimo de código ai que de para simular o seu problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode tentar fazer isso de uma maneira diferente: Pode criar uma nova classe com a largura de `150px` e ao clicar no botão, adicionar ela ao elemento.

CSS:

```
   .large {
      width: 150px;
   }
```

JS:

```
   function sidebarAnimation() {
        var sidebar = document.getElementById("sidebar");
        var sidebar_base = document.getElementById("sidebar_base");

        if(order) {
            sidebar.classList.add("large");
            sidebar_base.classList.add("large");
            
            order = false;
        } else {
            sidebar.classList.remove("large");
            sidebar_base.classList.remove("large");

            order = true;
        }
    }
```